# jQuery color blink animation

Tags: jquery, animation, colors

I'm trying to implement color blink animation, it animates but color don't return to original state, here is my code:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff').animate({
    'background-color': '#EFB15E'
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate('background-color', '#ffffff');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js"></script>
<div>Some Text</div>
```

Comment: You can do that with pure css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jxtje2bp/

Comment: Toggle a class as @Josef Drábek (indirectly) suggests :)

Comment: But can anyone say why OP's code is not working?? I also wonder why it is happening? May be it is because of the 3rd party plugin?

Comment: @JosefDrábek I need blink not toggle color.

Comment: @jcubic use keyframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your callback:

```
$(this).animate('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

has to be:

```
$(this).animate({'background-color': '#ffffff'});
```

`.animate()` expect a object as the first parameter.

Side-Note: Your Plugin `jQuery-Color` is included in the jQuery UI Library, see [here](https://jqueryui.com/animate/)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pd24b7vj/1/)